# Download a specific Blender source version from Git

Tags: development

I've installed and use official Blender 2.79 on my Os X. Now I'd like to better understand its structure, and try some development. So I'm trying to download hash 5bd8ac9 11-09-17 from git (the hash shown on the splash screen) so my development is aligned with the official one. 
Until now, no luck. I refer to https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/Git page on Blender dev wiki. My question:

How can I download a specific Blender source repo aligned with the official one? In other words, can someone point me to Blender 2.79 git sources?

Comment: those are three questions, this site requires one, please split your question.

Comment: Building blender is off topic on bse.  [Wiki Building on Mac](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Mac)   Consult git docs on how to branch and rewind head to a particular hash.

Comment: I see "building" is a very scary topic... anyway building is development, so you should amend tags by removing the "development" one.

Comment: Yes you're right. the tag should be removed from your question  as it's   _For coding questions about addon or script development, and the Python API. Does not include general programming questions, non blender specific tasks or errors, nor compilation of Blender binaries or questions pertaining to the C source code._

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't read the tiny bits...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check out the versions Tags and commit hashes here:
https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tags

1. `git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git` (and be patient as
   this is a monster repo!)
2. `cd blender`
3. `git checkout v2.79` (or whatever version you need)

You can also fetch only a specific tag from blenger.org however, not sure that will save you much ban(note that the blender git repo does allow only fetch from tagged or head branch commits, no arbitrary commit from hash) following those instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset

All that said, good luck with the build!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in one line:

```
git clone git://git.blender.org/blender.git -b blender2.79
```

I got that from the following discussion [correct branch for 2.79 build](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/whats-the-correct-branch-for-latest-2-7-builds/4590/4)